# Does resizing plots produce new data?

Tags: plotting

**What I do:**

- `ListPlot`,
- Select the plot area,
- A tooltip says: Double-click to edit,
- Double-click the line or a point on the line,
- Take a handle to resize the red frame or one  of the data points.
- Deselect the `Plot`.

[image]
[image]

**Questions:**

- Are there new values generated?
- How can you list those new values?

Comment: This question is essentially a duplicate of the one linked. The only part that is not addressed is trivial and the answer is yes, new values are created.

Comment: Sorry, which of those answers applies here? ListPlot does not take an EvaluationMonitor arg, and its done by the time we manipulate the data anyway.

Comment: There is a direct and simple way to do this. I'll add an answer to the other question unless someone cares to open this one.

Comment: I went and posted a new answer over there..http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14222/getting-a-list-of-accurate-coordinates-from-a-plot

Comment: After manipulating the plot on the graph area itself.   .  .Not give a new value to the formula.   .   .There is a very differend curve now.   .   .How to table the new values after changing the curve line in the plot area?   .   .Whitout rerunning the formula?

Comment: @HpRadojewskiSchäferVon exactly, see my answer to the other question.