# Does a manipulation of a plot area produce new data?

Tags: plotting

You do a ListPlot.

```
Plot[Sin[x^2], {x, 0, 1}]  
pdat1 = With[{fig = Plot[Sin[x^2], {x, 0, 1}]},   
First@Cases[fig, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity]];
```

[image: fig 1]
[image: fig 2]
[image: fig 3]
[image: fig 4]
[image: fig 5]
[image: fig 6]

You get your diagram. fig 1.
You select the ListPlot area.
A red fram shows.
A tooltip says: Double-click to edit. fig 2.
You Double-click the plot line.
Another red fram shows. fig 3.
You again Double-click the plot line.
The data points become visible. fig 4.
You take a handle to resize a data point. fig 5.
You deselect the Plot. fig 6.

There are now some new values constitute the diagram.
Question is:
How can you list/table the plot diagram values after this manipulation?

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25566/193

Answer (score 4):

You can do the following:-

```
    points = Cases[
    Cases[InputForm["Paste Here"], Line[___], 
     Infinity], {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, Infinity];
```

copy paste your modified plot where it says "Paste Here"

Now you can simply plot it

```
 ListLinePlot[points]
```

I got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5364088/mathematica-how-to-obtain-data-points-plotted-by-plot-command)