# 2D plot using output from the other function

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I would like to get 2D plot using output from the other function.

`FindInstance[0.5*x^2 + Cos[y + P] == 1, {x, y}, Reals]`

By changing values of P manually it gives instances for the expression.
Now I would like to draw a plot on {x,P} or {y,P} plane considering P as variable.

I tried following approach for {x,P} case,

`Plot[x /.FindInstance[0.5*x^2 + Cos[y + P] == 1, {x, y}, Reals], {P, 0, 100}]`

but it does not replace P in `FindInstance` instantly.

Is there some easy way to satisfy this problem?

Thanks for any help.

P.S. I don't insist on `FindInstance` if there is other suitable function for my case. As it could give result when called separately and crash in combination with other functions.

Comment: `f[p_] := x /. FindInstance[x^2 + Cos[y + p] == 1., {x, y}, Reals, 1];Plot[f[p], {p, 0, 10}]`.However, it is very slow.

Comment: Thank you. Here the other trouble appears. By changing the instant expression e.g `f[p_] := x /. 
  FindInstance[-0.5*(x - 1)^2 + Cos[y + p] == 1., {x, y}, Reals, 
   1]; Plot[f[p], {p, 0, 10}]`  it does not give any result.

Comment: So you need to re-consider your problem, because `x=1,y=-p` is always a solution. And when plotting the image of {x, p}, y can take a fixed value.

Comment: I mentioned trivial function for simplifying, the actual function is quite different. However in some cases if `FindInstance[]` was called separately it gives result, if it used in other function it crashed.

Comment: `y, p` are real, `Cos[y + p] <= 1`, so `-0.5*(x - 1)^2 >= 0`, this is impossible unless `x == 1`.

Comment: Fibonacci, I suspect that the "crash" of `FindInstance` was just the function giving you some errors. When I try to run your code, `FindInstance` reports that "The methods available to FindInstance are insufficient to find the requested instances or prove they do not exist. " That is valuable feedback: the function is telling you that it won't be able to extract a solution for you. It may be a limitation of the function, but it may also be an error in your code, which you might want to re-evaluate. Can you share what errors you experience, and what functions you are actually working with?

Comment: Amita, yes, for this selection of initial function the plot on {x,P} would be `x==1` line. But I want to get this result with Mathematica command and not analytically.

Comment: MarcoB, thank you. At this step it's useful me to understand why `FindInstance[-0.5*(x - 1)^2 + Cos[y + p] == 1., {x, y}, Reals, 1]` for any p provides the answer and `f[p_] := x /. 
  FindInstance[-0.5*(x - 1)^2 + Cos[y + p] == 1., {x, y}, Reals, 
   1]; Plot[f[p], {p, 0, 10}]` does not. Is that because of program limitations?

Answer (score 3):

This works much faster:

```
f[P_?NumericQ] := x /. FindMinimum[(0.5*x^2 + Cos[y + P] - 1)^2, {x, y}][[2]]
Plot[f[P], {P, 0, 100}]
```

> [image: plot]

It is possible to run it even faster if you will use a successive plotting algorithm (not the algorithm `Plot` uses) *and* provide optimal starting values for `FindMinimum` on each new step on the base on the optimal values found on the previous step. The following two threads contain solutions which can help you to implement this approach:

[How to implement the sample-point process like the built-ins of Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88299/280)

[How to obtain adaptive sampling as in Plot function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82912/280)

Comment: Alexy's answer also works on your second problem using `FindMinimum[(0.5*(x - 1)^2 + Cos[y + P] - 1)^2`. I don't know why `FindInstance` has problems but `FindMinimum` appears to be more robust for your particular problems.

Comment: By using `FindMinimum` it's significant availability of the unique solution. Meanwhile `FindInstance` gives instances of the same solution in general but cause problems e.g. http://i.imgur.com/4AuEoch.png . Anyway, Thank you for the interesting suggestion as the solution of the problem.