# How does Plot choose the points in a figure?

Tags: plotting, implementation-details

Taking a simple example,

```
f[x_]:=x^2 + 1
pic1 = Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> Red]
pts=Cases[pic1, Line[data1_] :> data1, Infinity]
pic2 = Reap[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}, EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x]];]
```

The result of pts is

```
{{{1.02041*10^-7, 1.}, {0.00153359, 1.}, {0.00306708, 
   1.00001}, {0.00460056, 1.00002}, {0.00613405, 
   1.00004}, {0.00766754, 1.00006}, {0.00920103, 1.00008}, {0.0107345,
    1.00012}, {0.012268, 1.00015}, {0.0138015, 1.00019}, {0.015335, 
   1.00024}, {0.0168685, 1.00028}, {0.018402, 1.00034}, {0.0199354, 
   1.0004}, {0.0214689, 1.00046}, {0.0245359, 1.0006}, {0.0260694, 
   1.00068}, {0.0276029, 1.00076}, {0.0306699, 1.00094}, {0.0322033, 
   1.00104}, {0.0337368, 1.00114}, {0.0368038, 1.00135}, {0.0383373, 
   1.00147}, {0.0398708, 1.00159}, {0.0429378, 1.00184}, {0.0490717, 
   1.00241}, {0.0506052, 1.00256}, {0.0521387, 1.00272}, {0.0552057, 
   1.00305}, {0.0613396, 1.00376}, {0.0628731, 1.00395}, {0.0644066, 
   1.00415}, {0.0674736, 1.00455}, {0.0736075, 1.00542}, {0.075141, 
   1.00565}, {0.0766745, 1.00588}, {0.0797415, 1.00636}, {0.0858754, 
   1.00737}, {0.0981433, 1.00963}, {0.0998058, 1.00996}, {0.101468, 
   1.0103}, {0.104793, 1.01098}, {0.111443, 1.01242}, {0.124743, 
   1.01556}, {0.126405, 1.01598}, {0.128068, 1.0164}, {0.131393, 
   1.01726}, {0.138043, 1.01906}, {0.151343, 1.0229}, {0.153005, 
   1.02341}, {0.154667, 1.02392}, {0.157992, 1.02496}, {0.164642, 
   1.02711}, {0.177942, 1.03166}, {0.204542, 1.04184}, {0.206094, 
   1.04247}, {0.207646, 1.04312}, {0.210751, 1.04442}, {0.21696, 
   1.04707}, {0.229379, 1.05261}, {0.254216, 1.06463}, {0.255768, 
   1.06542}, {0.25732, 1.06621}, {0.260425, 1.06782}, {0.266634, 
   1.07109}, {0.279053, 1.07787}, {0.303889, 1.09235}, {0.305411, 
   1.09328}, {0.306933, 1.09421}, {0.309977, 1.09609}, {0.316064, 
   1.0999}, {0.328239, 1.10774}, {0.352589, 1.12432}, {0.354111, 
   1.12539}, {0.355633, 1.12647}, {0.358676, 1.12865}, {0.364764, 
   1.13305}, {0.376939, 1.14208}, {0.401288, 1.16103}, {0.402939, 
   1.16236}, {0.40459, 1.16369}, {0.407892, 1.16638}, {0.414495, 
   1.17181}, {0.427702, 1.18293}, {0.454115, 1.20622}, {0.506942, 
   1.25699}, {0.508483, 1.25855}, {0.510024, 1.26012}, {0.513105, 
   1.26328}, {0.519268, 1.26964}, {0.531593, 1.28259}, {0.556244, 
   1.30941}, {0.605546, 1.36669}, {0.712404, 1.50752}, {0.817314, 
   1.668}, {0.915173, 1.83754}, {1.02129, 2.04303}, {1.12035, 
   2.25518}, {1.21746, 2.48222}, {1.32283, 2.74989}, {1.42115, 
   3.01968}, {1.52773, 3.33395}, {1.63235, 3.66458}, {1.72993, 
   3.99265}, {1.83576, 4.37001}, {1.93454, 4.74243}, {2.04157, 
   5.16801}, {2.14666, 5.60813}, {2.24469, 6.03864}, {2.35098, 
   6.52711}, {2.45022, 7.00358}, {2.54751, 7.48981}, {2.65306, 
   8.0387}, {2.75155, 8.57103}, {2.8583, 9.16988}, {2.9631, 
   9.77997}, {3.06085, 10.3688}, {3.16686, 11.029}, {3.26581, 
   11.6655}, {3.36282, 12.3085}, {3.46808, 13.0276}, {3.56629, 
   13.7184}, {3.67275, 14.4891}, {3.77217, 15.2293}, {3.86964, 
   15.9741}, {3.97536, 16.8035}, {4.07403, 17.5977}, {4.18095, 
   18.4804}, {4.28593, 19.3692}, {4.38386, 20.2182}, {4.49004, 
   21.1604}, {4.58917, 22.0605}, {4.68635, 22.9619}, {4.79179, 
   23.9612}, {4.89017, 24.9138}, {4.89189, 24.9306}, {4.8936, 
   24.9474}, {4.89704, 24.981}, {4.9039, 25.0482}, {4.91763, 
   25.1831}, {4.94509, 25.4539}, {4.9468, 25.4708}, {4.94852, 
   25.4878}, {4.95195, 25.5218}, {4.95881, 25.5898}, {4.97254, 
   25.7262}, {4.97426, 25.7433}, {4.97597, 25.7603}, {4.97941, 
   25.7945}, {4.98627, 25.8629}, {4.98799, 25.88}, {4.9897, 
   25.8971}, {4.99314, 25.9314}, {4.99485, 25.9485}, {4.99657, 
   25.9657}, {4.99828, 25.9828}, {5., 26.}}}
```

And the result of pic2 is

```
{Null, {{1.02041*10^-7, 0.0981433, 
   0.204542, 0.303889, 0.401288, 0.506942, 0.605546, 0.712404, 
   0.817314, 0.915173, 1.02129, 1.12035, 1.21746, 1.32283, 1.42115, 
   1.52773, 1.63235, 1.72993, 1.83576, 1.93454, 2.04157, 2.14666, 
   2.24469, 2.35098, 2.45022, 2.54751, 2.65306, 2.75155, 2.8583, 
   2.9631, 3.06085, 3.16686, 3.26581, 3.36282, 3.46808, 3.56629, 
   3.67275, 3.77217, 3.86964, 3.97536, 4.07403, 4.18095, 4.28593, 
   4.38386, 4.49004, 4.58917, 4.68635, 4.79179, 4.89017, 5., 
   0.0490717, 0.151343, 0.254216, 0.352589, 0.454115, 0.556244, 
   4.94509, 0.0245359, 0.124743, 0.229379, 0.328239, 0.427702, 
   0.531593, 4.91763, 0.0736075, 0.177942, 0.279053, 0.376939, 
   4.97254, 0.012268, 0.111443, 0.21696, 0.316064, 0.414495, 0.519268,
    4.9039, 0.0613396, 0.164642, 0.266634, 0.364764, 4.95881, 
   0.0368038, 0.138043, 0.0858754, 4.98627, 0.00613405, 0.104793, 
   0.210751, 0.309977, 0.407892, 0.513105, 4.89704, 0.0552057, 
   0.157992, 0.260425, 0.358676, 4.95195, 0.0306699, 0.131393, 
   0.0797415, 4.97941, 0.018402, 0.0674736, 0.0429378, 4.99314, 
   0.00306708, 0.101468, 0.207646, 0.306933, 0.40459, 0.510024, 
   4.8936, 0.0521387, 0.154667, 0.25732, 0.355633, 4.94852, 0.0276029,
    0.128068, 0.0766745, 4.97597, 0.015335, 0.0644066, 0.0398708, 
   4.9897, 0.00920103, 0.0337368, 0.0214689, 4.99657, 0.00153359, 
   0.0998058, 0.206094, 0.305411, 0.402939, 0.508483, 4.89189, 
   0.0506052, 0.153005, 0.255768, 0.354111, 4.9468, 0.0260694, 
   0.126405, 0.075141, 4.97426, 0.0138015, 0.0628731, 0.0383373, 
   4.98799, 0.00766754, 0.0322033, 0.0199354, 4.99485, 0.00460056, 
   0.0168685, 0.0107345, 4.99828}}}
```

I have two questions:

1. The x point in the two sets of data are different. Why?
2. In the Reap/Sow method, the x points do not increase monotonically. It seems that the Sow function sow x points from small to large several times. Why?

Thank you!

Comment: What is `data1`?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork It is just a pattern name.

Comment: Without you defining it, I don't see how we can help.

Comment: `Sort[pic2[[2, 1]]] == pts[[1, All, 1]]` gives `True`.

Comment: @kglr Thanks. That solves my first question!

Comment: The method described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89717) is more or less how old *Mathematica* implemented adaptive sampling. The current version is a slightly refined version of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** sampled x values are the same but ordered differently:

```
Sort[pic2[[2, 1]]] == pts[[1, All, 1]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

**2.** Total number of x values and their ordering depends on the option settings for `PlotPoints` and `MaxRecursion`. With `MaxRecursion -> 0` and `PlotPoints -> n`, `n` equally spaced values are sampled.

- *`PlotPoints -> n` specifies the total number of initial sample
  points to use.*
- *Adaptive procedures controlled by `MaxRecursion` are used to choose more sample points*.

As an illustration, specify a small value for `PlotPoints` and examine the sampled values for different values for `MaxRecursion`:

```
sampledxvalues[mr_] := Reap[Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5},
    PlotPoints -> 12, MaxRecursion -> mr, 
    EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x]]][[2, 1]]

NumberLinePlot[sampledxvalues /@ {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {sampledxvalues@0, 
    Automatic}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {.05, .5}, 
 Spacings -> {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, 
 ImageSize -> 900, 
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 16] & /@ {"X", "MaxRecursion"})]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[MapIndexed[Callout[#, #2[[1]]] &] /@ 
  Thread /@ Thread[{sampledxvalues /@ Range[0, 2], Range[0, 2]}], 
 ImageSize -> 900, 
 BaseStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[2], 
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Range[0, 2], Automatic}, {sampledxvalues@0, 
    Automatic}}, 
 Axes -> False, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {.05, .5}, 
 FrameLabel -> {{Style["MaxRecursion", 16], None}, {Style["x", 16], None}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That solves my questions very well.

Answer (score 3):

How it chooses the points is easy. It is an adaptive sampler. If it detects the function is changing rapidly, then it increases the sampling rate (more points for same interval). If the function changes less rapidly, it reduces the sampling rate. You can see this by doing

```
f[x_] := x^2 + 1
pic1 = Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotPoints -> 10];
pts1 = First@Cases[pic1, Line[data1_] :> data1, Infinity];
ListPlot[pts1, Mesh -> All, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

As to why when you used `EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[x]` the `x` values seem to be different, I am not sure why. Here is a plot showing the difference for first  50 points

```
f[x_] := x^2 + 1
pic1 = Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red, PlotPoints -> 10];
pts1 = First@Cases[pic1, Line[data1_] :> data1, Infinity];
pts2 = First@
   Last@Reap[
     Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 10, 
      EvaluationMonitor :> Sow[{x, f[x]}]]];
Show[
 ListPlot[pts1[[1 ;; 50]], Mesh -> All, PlotStyle -> Red],
 ListPlot[pts2[[1 ;; 50]], Mesh -> All, PlotStyle -> Blue]
 ]
```

[image]

The strange thing is that both have same number of points

```
Length@pts1
Length@pts2
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It is possible that `EvaluationMonitor` uses it own algorithm when it is called, but uses the same number of points, that is why they match? I do not know. Hopefully someone will know better why the the `x` values are different.