# how can I list x, y axes values of a graph

Tags: plotting

```
n = 0; a = 1; L = 0; m = 1/2; b = 100; g = (2 m a r)/(n + L + 1);

Fi[r_] = (r)^(L + 1) Exp[-((  m a)/(n + L + 1)) r] LaguerreL[n, 2 L + 1, g];


f[r_] = AiryAi[(2 m b)^(1/3)  (r)];

Plot[{r^(L + 1) f[r], Fi[r] f[r]}, {r, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Look up `Table[]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot, extract data to a file](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19859/plot-extract-data-to-a-file)

Comment: Or http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14222/18476

Answer (score 1):

The duplicate that Karsten pointed to I think is overkill for this.  Just a simple [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) is all you need, and you can display it easily with [`TableForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TableForm.html)

```
dr = 0.05;
data =  Table[{r, r^(L + 1) f[r], Fi[r] f[r]}, {r, 0, 1, dr}];
TableForm[
 data,
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"r", "r^(L+1) f[r]", "Fi[r] f[r]"}}
 ]
```

Comment: thank you so much Jason. You saved me from the arrogant one.my soon and daughter thanks to you, too.