# How can I extract data from a diagram?

Tags: image-processing, data-acquisition

Below you will see a diagram containing three curves.

[image]

How can I extract data points from the three colored curves? I need to use the original data.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44355/how-to-make-a-curve-selectable-from-a-scaned-image-and-convert-it-to-a-list-of-c

Comment: ……同学，你到底是想从图片（Image）上挖点呢，还是想从Plot之类的函数画出的图（Graphics）里面挖点？实在说不清楚的话可以用中文表达下。

Comment: @xzczd, Ren Qi Pan is a new contributor .............

Comment: @ABCDEMMM I know, and that's the reason why I'm trying to communicate in Chinese. Given that the [original version](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/revisions/185009/1) of this question isn't that clear, and OP doesn't reply to the question in (now deleted) comment for quite a while, I suppose (s)he is having difficulty in saying what (s)he wants to say.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have language barriers. I wanna get the original data(containing lots of points) of the image. In the following answers, someone have solved the problem. Thank you agian, anyhow.

Comment: You need to add @xzczd in your comment or I won't get the reminder. Since you deleted the line "I only have the image", do you mean have the code generating the `Graphics` (Something like `Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,100}]`) at hand?

Comment: Original data instead of pixels are wannted. May be I shoud use the word ''diagram'' rather than ''image", so I editted the question again to make it more clearer.

Comment: I mean, where does the "diagram" come from? Is it generated by _Mathematica_ code like `Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,100}]`, or a screenshot/image similar to the one shown in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/44355/1871)?

Comment: In other words, do you agree your post is a duplicate of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14222/1871), [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19859/1871) or [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31858/1871). If not, why?

Answer (score 18):

this code produces the three lists of data that you want
   orange,blue and green

```
s = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR8Gg.gif"];
t = ImageData@s;
h = Union@Flatten[t, 1];
p = FindClusters@h;
F[x_] := (# - {20, 29}) {3/350, 3/100} & /@ 
Select[Flatten[PixelValuePositions[s, RGBColor[#]] & /@ p[[x]], 
1], #[[1]] > 20 && #[[2]] > 29 &]
orange = F[5];
blue = F[1];
green = F[2];


ListPlot[{blue, orange, green}]
```

[image]

Here is the second approach for clustering which was proposed in the comments section

```
s = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR8Gg.gif"];
t = ImageData@s;
h = Union@Flatten[t, 1];
p = FindClusters[RGBColor @@@ h];
F[x_] := (# - {21, 29}) {3/350, 3/100} & /@ 
Select[Flatten[PixelValuePositions[s, #] & /@ p[[x]], 
1], #[[1]] > 21 && #[[2]] > 29 &]
orange = F[3];
blue = F[1];
green = F[2];
```

this gives the same picture but returns more data points in every list
using

```
Length /@ {blue, orange, green}
```

first version

> {1375, 1228, 1259}

second version

> {1534, 1440, 1502}

Comment: Works great on 10.4, fails on 11.3, where I only get 4 clusters in p.

Comment: You just have to try another cluster by changing the value p[[5]]..

Comment: This is interesting. I just compared `FindClusters` on lists of 3 numbers vs colors. It works better when it knows it is clustering colors. That is `FindClusters[RGBColor @@@ h]` instead of just `FindClusters[h]`

Comment: very nice. I also fixed the scale. I really have to go now so I will implement your idea later. (or feel free to edit yourself)