# Is it possible to extract data from a Mathematica plot and plot it with the Origin software?

Tags: plotting

I have combined three plots with "Show[p1,p2,p3]. Can I extract the data points from my plot and want to plot with origin??
[image]`

```
F = 0.025;
kv = 0.0043;
kw = 0.046;
A = (F + kv);
B = (F + kw);
Du = 290;
Dv = 100.443;
Dw = 7.3;
G = (F - Sqrt[F^2 - 4*F*(A^2 + B^2)])^2;
j11 = (-((4*F^2*(A^2 + B^2))*G^(-1)) - F);
j12 = -(2*A);
j13 = -(2*B);
j21 = (4*A^2*F^2)/(G);
j22 = (A);
j31 = (4*B^2*F^2)/G;
j33 = B;

C1 = (k^2 (Du + Dv + Dw) - j11 - j22 - j33);

C2 = ((-j11*(Dv + Dw) - j22*(Du + Dw) - j33*(Du + Dv))*
     k^2 + (Du*Dv + Du*Dw + Dv*Dw)*k^4 - j12*j21 - j13*j31 + j11*j22 +
     j11*j33 + j22*j33);

C3 = ((Du*Dv*Dw)*k^6 + (-j11*Dv*Dw - j22*Du*Dw - j33*Du*Dv)*
     k^4 + (Dw*j11*j22 + Dv*j11*j33 + Du*j22*j33 - Dw*j12*j21 - 
       Dv*j13*j31)*k^2 - j11*j22*j33 + j12*j21*j33 + j13*j31*j22);
p1 = ContourPlot[
  x^3 + (C1) *x^2 + (C2)*x + C3 == 0, {k, 0.005, 0.020}, {x, -0.01, 
   0.008}, ContourStyle -> Magenta]
```

`
Then repeated the same code with Different Dv=149 and Dv=174, combine the three plots with Show[p1,p2, p3]

Comment: Strongly related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14222/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31858/1871

Comment: This question might be a duplicate, but also might not be, depending how the mentioned combined plot looks like. Can you provide an image of your combined plot?

Comment: Anton AntonovThank you so much for your reply  I have added the image file here.

Comment: Do you have the code to generate this plot, Albert, or do you only have an image of the plot?

Comment: @CarlLange Yes I have but I am new here, so i don't know ho to add code in my comments

Comment: Click "edit" under your question and paste the code into your question. Then select your code and click the icon in the textbox toolbar that looks like {}. That will format your code. Then save your question.

Comment: @CarlLange Yes dear, I did it here,  thank you so much,

Comment: Can anyone help, please ??

Comment: Please define what "redraw from origin" means.

Comment: @AntonAntonov I want to plot with origin.

Comment: @Albert I still don't get it - the point $(0,0)$ is visible in the plot - do you want to center it around that point? Also, why can you not change the original plot command? Why do you want to extract the data from an existing plot? (which is way messier)

Comment: @AntonAntonov from "origin" I mean to Plot in "origin" software. 
I need text file of the Datapoints, so that I use an other software to plot it

Comment: All this fuss and to-do over the lack of an uppercase `O` on `origin` in the original post !

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Yeah, a complete waste of time...

Comment: @AntonAntonov Thank you dude, I really appreciate your effort. sorry for taking your time, I think I didn't convey my question properly.  
sorry again for taking your time

Comment: @Albert It is ok, good luck!

Answer (score 9):

> @AntonAntonov I want to plot with origin. – Albert

I think OP wants this (it is not entirely clear):

```
F = 0.025;
kv = 0.0043;
kw = 0.046;
A = (F + kv);
B = (F + kw);
Du = 290;
(*Dv=100.443;*)
Dw = 7.3;
G = (F - Sqrt[F^2 - 4*F*(A^2 + B^2)])^2;
j11 = (-((4*F^2*(A^2 + B^2))*G^(-1)) - F);
j12 = -(2*A);
j13 = -(2*B);
j21 = (4*A^2*F^2)/(G);
j22 = (A);
j31 = (4*B^2*F^2)/G;
j33 = B;

{kmin, kmax} = {0.005, 0.020};

grs =
  MapThread[
   Function[{Dv, color},
    C1 = (k^2 (Du + Dv + Dw) - j11 - j22 - j33);
    C2 = ((-j11*(Dv + Dw) - j22*(Du + Dw) - j33*(Du + Dv))*
        k^2 + (Du*Dv + Du*Dw + Dv*Dw)*k^4 - j12*j21 - j13*j31 + 
       j11*j22 + j11*j33 + j22*j33);
    C3 = ((Du*Dv*Dw)*k^6 + (-j11*Dv*Dw - j22*Du*Dw - j33*Du*Dv)*
        k^4 + (Dw*j11*j22 + Dv*j11*j33 + Du*j22*j33 - Dw*j12*j21 - 
          Dv*j13*j31)*k^2 - j11*j22*j33 + j12*j21*j33 + j13*j31*j22);
    ContourPlot[
     x^3 + (C1)*x^2 + (C2)*x + C3 == 0, {k, kmin, kmax}, {x, -0.01, 
      0.008}, ContourStyle -> color, PlotRange -> All]
    ], {{100.443, 149, 174}, {Red, Blue, Green}}];

Show[grs, PlotRange -> {{-kmin, kmax}, All}, GridLines -> {{0}, {0}}, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.03], Point[{0, 0}], Black, 
   Text[Style["Origin", Bold], {0, 0}, {-1, -1}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for banter related arguments.

Comment: @QuantumPenguin Thanks, I spent too much time coding in order to get OP to say `from "origin" I mean to Plot in "origin" software.`

Comment: Totally worth it, this really tickled me.

Comment: Totally worth an upvote.